# ZfcUser setup issue

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to setup ZfcUser as described in README.md on the github page.
I understand all but this step in Post-Install: Zend\Db;
2. Now, specify the DI alias for your PDO connection in ./configs/autoload/module.zfcuser.config.php, under the 'pdo' setting. If you created the ./config/autoload/database.config.php file in the previous step, the alias you'll specify is 'masterdb'.

Can anyone describe me what exactly to do?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Manage to fix this by updating the parameter name in module.config.php for ZfcUser. Corrected from

```
  'zfcuser_user_tg' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'table' => 'user',
                'adapter'   => 'zfcuser_zend_db_adapter',
            ),
        ),
        'zfcuser_usermeta_tg' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'table' => 'user_meta',
                'adapter'   => 'zfcuser_zend_db_adapter',
            ),
        ),
```

to

```
'zfcuser_user_tg' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'tableName' => 'user',
                'adapter'   => 'zfcuser_zend_db_adapter',
            ),
        ),
        'zfcuser_usermeta_tg' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'tableName' => 'user_meta',
                'adapter'   => 'zfcuser_zend_db_adapter',
            ),
        ),
```

table => corrected to tableName

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The solution was to uncomment line 15 in module.zfcuser.config.php  and not use the 'masterdb' ...

'zend_db_adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',

See support issue ...
https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/issues/42